# Visualize sklearn stackingclassifier model pipeline construct

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

With `scikit-learn` pipeline we can visualize our pipeline construct. See below screenshot.

[image]

I couldn't find similar plotting feature for a sklearn stacking classifier. How can I represent the ensemble model construct with sklearn stacking classifier?

Answer (score 1):

Just like voting classifier, StackingClassifier too could be added as a component of the model pipeline as shown below:[image]